# Why does multiple calls to printf following a pragma omp critical produce garbled output?

Tags: c++, c, openmp

I have two programs that spawn multiple threads and print `hello <TID> world <TID>` to stdout.
The first prints it in one function:

```
#include <omp.h>                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                               
int main() {                               
#pragma omp parallel                       
  {                                        
    int ID = omp_get_thread_num();         
#pragma omp critical                                  
    printf("hello  %d world %d\n", ID, ID);                                  
  }      
  return 0;                                  
}
```

The second in two:

```
#include <omp.h>                                                  
#include <stdio.h>                                           
int main() {                               
#pragma omp parallel                       
  {                                        
    int ID = omp_get_thread_num();         
#pragma omp critical                       
    printf("hello  %d", ID);             
    printf("world %d\n", ID);                                                
  }  
  return 0;                                      
}
```

With the program with a single call to `printf()`, the output is never garbled. 
However, with the second program, two calls to `printf()`, the output is garbled.
With the second program, there is never garbling that interferes with the string sequences; never something of the sort `hhhhellloohello...`.  There is however garbling between the distinct output strings; a permutation of the possibilities:

```
hello  27hello  62hello  52hello  50hello  10world 62...
```

as an example.

I thought `#pragma omp critical` would assert mutual exclusion following the `pragma` until the end of the parallelised block. But that does not seem to be the case.
Does `#pragma omp critical` only apply to the statement immediately following it?

Any insight why this occurs would be great.
Izaak

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like `#pragma omp parallel`, [`#pragma omp critical`](http://bisqwit.iki.fi/story/howto/openmp/#CriticalConstruct) is restricted to only the next line, unless you also make it a block.

If you don't want interleaved output, use another set of curly braces:

```
#pragma omp critical                       
{
    printf("hello  %d", ID);             
    printf("world %d\n", ID); 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably it is because POSIX requires single I/O function calls to be thread-safe, but does not require locking between separate function calls.  The relevant part of the specification is well-hidden on the page about:

- [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html)
- `funlockfile()`
- `ftrylockfile()`

The relevant part of the specification is near the end:

> All functions that reference (`FILE *`) objects, except those with names ending in `_unlocked`, shall behave as if they use `flockfile()` and `funlockfile()` internally to obtain ownership of these (`FILE *`) objects.

That means, for example, that `printf()` must do (the equivalent of) `flockfile(stdout)` on entry and (the equivalent of) `funlockfile(stdout)` on exit.

This matches exactly what you're seeing with the OMP code.  The text from a single call to `printf()` is not interleaved with any other concurrent call, but the sequence of the `printf()` calls is interleaved between threads.

Comment: Ok, so, interleaving between calls, but not within them, is the reason for a permutation of the output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b38674ky.aspx), you can see that the code that should be run by a single thread at a time should be placed into a code block.

It's also a good idea to add a name, so that if you use multiple such directives they don't conflict,